# Using video chat apis for IOS without managing the serverside

Tags: swift, twilio, opentok, videochat

I am looking for some ready-to-go APIs provided by platforms to deal with video chatting etc. There are some examples like Twilio or OpenTok but you have to create the server side by yourself.

Are there any other examples where I don't have to deal with the server?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to try ConnectyCube, they have a Swift code sample for video calling

You do not need to bother with any server-side stuff, can concentrate only on client-side app development

- Code samples https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/code-samples
- Video Chat swift code sample https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-ios-samples/tree/master/sample-videochat-swift
- Getting Started guide https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/
- Video Chat API documentation https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/videocalling

The following features are supported:

- 1-1 video chat
- Group video chat
- Cross-platform
- Screen sharing
- WebRTC based
- End-to-end Encryption by default
- VP8/H264 video codecs supported
- Mute/Unmute audio/video stream
- Switch video input devices (cameras)
- Video recording

Answer (score 0):

> **Vidyo.io**

You can use this its free for 2000 minutes but it will work without a `server`,

https://vidyo.io/platform/mobile/